# How to get alert to display properly based on number of inputs?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, alert

i'm in a very beginner javascript course and we were tasked with making a simple loop "program". I settled on asking users for names of colors and based on how many answers they come up with, it would display some kind of result message.

I got the initial question prompt to work asking for color names but no matter what i do or where I try to put my alert code, it doesn't seem to work, any guidance on where to go from here? tried changing i in the alert pop up statements to colorNames and cName but still nothing

```
// variable for while loop
var colorNames = [];
var keepRunning = true;

// keep naming colors until done
while (keepRunning) {

    var newColor = prompt('Name as many colors as you can!' + "\n" + 'If you can\'t think of any more, leave empty and hit OK.');

    //test if prompt box has something in it or not
    if (newColor.length > 0) {
        colorNames.push(newColor);
    } else {
        keepRunning = false;
    }
}

// display color names entered 
for (var i = 0; i < colorNames.length; i++) {

    var cName = colorNames[i];
    document.write(cName + "  ");

}

//alert pop up based on number of inputs
if (keepRunning = false) {
    if (i <= 4) {
        alert('That\'s all you could think of? Refresh and try again!')
    } else if (i <= 8) {
        alert('Not bad, but you can probably do better. Refresh to play again.')
    } else if (i <= 12) {
        alert('Wow! You really know your colors! You can refresh to challenge yourself again!')
    } else if (i >= 15) {
        alert('I don\'t think anyone could do better than this, nice job!')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues in your logic preventing it from working:

1. In the `if (keepRunning = false)` condition `=` needs to be `==` or `===`. A single `=` is for assigning a value, not comparison of values.
2. Outside of your `for` loop, `i` is not accessible. You can fix the code, and make it more semantic, by using `colorNames.length` in the `if` conditions instead.

In addition, there's some general improvements you can make:

- Never use `document.write()`. Either update the Elements in the DOM or create new ones. In the following example I create `<p>` elements to display the text.
- After the colours have been set, `keepRunning` will *always* be `false`, so there's no point checking it in another `if` statement.
- Set a variable to hold the output message, then call `alert()` once.
- There's no need to comment every line. If the logic is easy enough to follow, they are unnecessary.

Here's working example with the above amendments made:

```js
const colorNames = [];
let keepRunning = true;
const container = document.querySelector('#output');

while (keepRunning) {
  var newColor = prompt('Name as many colors as you can!' + "\n" + 'If you can\'t think of any more, leave empty and hit OK.');
  if (newColor.length > 0) {
    colorNames.push(newColor);
  } else {
    keepRunning = false;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < colorNames.length; i++) {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = colorNames[i];
  container.append(p);
}

let outputMessage = 'That\'s all you could think of? Refresh and try again!';
if (colorNames.length <= 8) {
  outputMessage = 'Not bad, but you can probably do better. Refresh to play again.';
} else if (colorNames.length <= 12) {
  outputMessage = 'Wow! You really know your colors! You can refresh to challenge yourself again!';
} else if (colorNames.length >= 15) {
  outputMessage = 'I don\'t think anyone could do better than this, nice job!';
}
alert(outputMessage);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! i made some changes to my own code based off your feedback and got it to work :)